# Saving huge amount of data (nearly 20 billion entries) in django postgresql

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to save about 15-20 billion entries in django model and I'm using postgresql. I tried to use django bulk_create but my computer got stuck for nearly 45 minutes and then I shut the code now. My question is, how to do this in the right way?

Comment: Are you having SQL dump file of data? What is the source of your data?

Comment: I would do this in chunks, say 1 million each. Bulk inserts of course. This is still going to take a good amount of time. The numbers seem crazy to use postgresql, though.

Comment: @TammoHeeren True, that's a lot of data for PostgreSQL if these are the entries for single table

Comment: I disagree that this question should be put on hold, as all the information related to particular issue is already present here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anonymous is right about dump files being the best way to load data from/to databases.

If you don't have access to the database in order to create a dump file, it might be harder, so a python way to make it work would be to `bulk_create` in batches.

For example:

```
inserts = []
last = len(entries)
batch_size = 10000

for i, entry in enumerate(entries):  ## or your datasource
    # transform data to django object
    inserts.append(EntryObject(attribute='attributes...'))

    if i % batch_size == 0 or i == last:

        EntryObject.bulk_create(inserts)  # insert batch

        inserts = []  # reset batch
```

Then again, it depends on your datasource. Also you might want to look into running them as asynchronous tasks if it needs to be called as part of a Django view.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your system would have ran out of memory (RAM). Ideal way would be to create the SQL dump file (assuming you are getting 20 billion records from another DB). And then load this SQL file into the new DB. All the data present in dump file will be loaded into PostgreSQL.

For creating the Dump file, do:

```
 $ pg_dump -U {user-name} {source_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

For Restoring from dump file, do:

```
 $ psql -U {user-name} -d {desintation_db}-f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

Check: [How To Backup and Restore PostgreSQL Database Using pg_dump and psql](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/how-to-backup-and-restore-postgres-database-using-pg_dump-and-psql/) for detailed information

Comment: It did run out of memory. My source for data are loads of text files. So I did a  batch bulk_create. I do need dump for uploading all this to RDS though. Thanks.